# document cookie / Got an error "Illegal document.domain value"

Tags: javascript, dns, document

while using document cookie

```
<script typ="text/javascript"> 
        document.domain="example.com"; 
</script>
```

I got an error.i don't know the exact problem.

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal document.domain
>   value" code: "1009" nsresult: "0x805303f1
>   (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_DOCUMENT_DOMAIN)" location: ""]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the HTML spec, `document.domain` is read-only. However, Firefox allows setting it to a superdomain:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain

> In the DOM HTML specification, this property is listed as being
>   read-only. However, Mozilla will let you set it to a superdomain of
>   the current value, constrained by its base domain. For example, on
>   developer.mozilla.org it is possible to set it to "mozilla.org" but
>   not "mozilla.com" or "org".

The error you're getting clearly states that you're making an illegal domain assignment.

You mention cookies in your question. If you're trying to set the domain part of a cookie, setting `document.domain` has nothing to do with it. You need to provide a domain parameter as part of the cookie string that you're assigning:

```
document.cookie = "foo=bar;domain=example.com";
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

Answer (score 0):

it works on IE as well. it's for same origin, we need to shorten the domain name.